# Sqlite Prepared Statement, don't change value / keep same as existing? (Android)

Tags: android, sqlite, prepared-statement

Lets say I have the prepared statement as follows;

```
"UPDATE table1 SET column1 = ?, column2 = ? WHERE column3 = ?"
```

Is it possible to use this statement to only change the value of column1 or column2? As you might imagine my problem is a bit more complex than the example, but basically I will only have some of the column values available for updating and there is a lot of different varients, and it would get quite messy creating prepared statements for each case.

I initially thought I could just set the column name as the parameter, but this doesn't work, I suspect because the parameters just get escaped as strings.

I imagine sub queries would work, but this would probably be more work and less understandable to achieve programatically than just having a statement for each case.

So, what are my options please? Thanks!

Comment: What do you want to achieve ? If it is updating some columns of a table, then the above example would work.

Comment: I know how to update columns in a table and I know this works already, but specifically I am wondering if its possible to leave one (or more) of the columns stated in the prepared statement unmodified, so it retains its original value in the DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using parameters, the parameter values are literal values, i.e., they are not executed or interpreted in any way.

The only way to get the old value into this statement is to read it with a separate query, and use the result of that query as the parameter value.

SQLite is not a client/server database, so there is no big overhead for preparing statement. Just use multiple prepared statements, or simply construct them on the fly all the time.

Comment: Thanks, yea I thought this would be the case, I have opted for lots of prepared statements instead. I only really need to do this because of some server api inconsistencies anyway, so once we get those ironed out I should be able to clean it up more. Thanks for your response.